# Conemu - how to add a command "npm start" when tab opens?

Tags: bash, cmd.exe, conemu

I have following bash startup script in Conemu console:

> -new_console:d:C:\git\AgentReporting\src\AgentReporting.Client\agent-reporting-client set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%..\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuDir%..\Git\git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:s20V

How to add "npm start" command to this?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartCmd.html

Comment: I tried many ways and I don't know how to do that even if I look into this documentation...

Comment: So, you've asked wrong question. For question "how to run npm start in task" the answer is just run it in the task. Posted link to docs explains more complicated workflow.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean... But by the way thank you for your hard work on this nice program mister @Maximus

Comment: I mean "execute some command on bash startup and leave the shell running thereafter". Solution is as simple as `cmd /k bla-bla-bla` for cmd, but is rather complicated for bash. Your question is not about that case. You don't need bash running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do that... But hell, it was hard to find any examples on the Internet.

> -new_console:d:C:\git\AgentReporting\src\AgentReporting.Client\agent-reporting-client set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%..\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuDir%..\Git\git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:s20Vt:"Ng Serve" -c "npm start"

Above script runs the bash console.

**-new_console:d:C:\git\AgentReporting\src\AgentReporting.Client\agent-reporting-client** - starting directory

**s20Vt** - it will open only in 20% of the window size, vertically, on the bottom.

**t:"Ng Serve"** - with the tab name "Ng Serve"

**-c "npm start"** - runs the command "npm start"

Answer (score 0):

Same for me it was super hard to find any information on internet.

Your solution didn't work for me, what worked was to add `&& myCommand` at the end of the Task's script. If I take your example in your question that would become

> -new_console:d:C:\git\AgentReporting\src\AgentReporting.Client\agent-reporting-client set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%..\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuDir%..\Git\git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:s20V **&& npm start**

You can even combine multiple commands with as many `&& command` as you want

> -new_console:d:C:\git\AgentReporting\src\AgentReporting.Client\agent-reporting-client set "PATH=%ConEmuDir%..\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuDir%..\Git\git-cmd.exe --no-cd --command=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i -new_console:s20V **&& npm i && npm run build && npm start**